# The Index role of a custom variable in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Can someone please clarify whether it's possible to have 5 custom variables with key names: A1, B1, C1, D1 and E1 in a single pageview/event and having another 5 custom variables with names A2, B2, C2, D2 and E2 in another pageview? assuming you are using indexes 1 to 5.

BTW - I'm using the mobile SDK on Android.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Its not about the limits, its about what you want to do with those custom variables. Custom Variables can be set in 3 ways > page - session and visit.

What is the name of that A1, B1 and C1, etc.?

```
<code>_setCustomVar(1, "Give a name", "A", 3)</code>
```

3 - at the end - means its a page-level variable.

Comment: Hi, it's written that 5 custom variables is the maximum you can have, regardless of the scope (page, session, visitor), I wanted to know whether it's max 5 per page/request or mx 5 in total.

Comment: It says its 5 but a guy [here](http://analyticsimpact.com/2010/05/24/get-more-than-5-custom-variables-in-google-analytics/) made 10 of them 2 years ago.

Comment: The max variables is now set to 50 in the sdk but only premium users can have more than 5, the call to setMaxVariables only expand the allocated space in the client sdk, I recall seeing another reference that the extra variables weren't accessible via GA web interface even though they are listed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes; as long as you're only using page level custom variables.  If you try to change between page and session, read Google Docs on [mixing Custom Variable types](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables#mixedTypes).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm aware about the possibility of reusing indexes, this is why I asked my question. What you say basically is that only page-level custom variables are reusable? why not visitor level custom-variables as well? do you have a reference for that?

I'm asking whether it's possible to use 5 variables of the same type in one page-request (without index collision) and then use 5 different variables in another request, without index collision as well per the request